# Include the Help search box in the header, so it's available on all Help pages not just the launching page

Tags: feature-request, search, help-center

After using the search box on the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help), I often want to search again. But there isn't a search box on the page I've arrived at. Or rather there is, but it's not the Help search, but the site search (which I'm quite likely to inadvertently use instead, in the absence of anything else in my face after reading the help topic for a while!).

I think it would be useful to include the Help search box in the header, so it's available on all Help pages.